# Why does installing angular-devise via bower actually install AngularDevise?

Tags: angularjs, bower

When i run

```
bower i --save angular-devise
```

I end up with `AngularDevise` in my bower.json, instead of `angular-devise`, though it looks like it indirectly installs it.

bower.json looks like

```
  "dependencies": {
    "AngularDevise": "angular-devise#^1.3.0"
  }
```

Note `AngularDevise` VS `angular-devise`.

Why does it not just install the latter?

Apologies in advance if this is a newbie question.

Comment: Also, in my application.js I had to use "//= require AngularDevise" - as "//= require angular-devise" didn't work.